# Javascript, how to pass parent function parameter to child function with callback arguments?

Tags: javascript

I have a PayPal checkout button, and a form validation function, which is like this:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    commit: true,
    style: {
        size: 'small',
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'buynow',
        height: 38
    },
    locale: 'it_IT',
    onInit: function (data, actions) {
        //Disable paypal button on init
        //actions.disable();
    },
    onClick: function (data, actions) {

        //Validate form and keep doing paypal logic only if success
        validateFormData(null, function () {

            ////////// HERE ACTIONS ARE NOT DEFINED /////////////
            return actions.resolve(); //Continue paypal logic

        }, function () {

            ////////// HERE ACTIONS ARE NOT DEFINED /////////////
            return actions.reject(); //Reject paypal logic

        });

    },
    createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        //mylogic
    },
    onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        //mylogic
    },
}).render('#paypal-button-container');

function validateFormData(beforeSend, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    $.post({
        url: 'myurl',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: getFormData(),
        beforeSend: function () {
            clearFormValidationErrors();
            if (beforeSend != null) {
                beforeSend();
            }
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (!response.success && response.data.validation_error) {
                //Show errors on the form
                showFormValidationErrors(response.data.validation_fields);
                onFailure();
            } else if (response.success) {
                onSuccess();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

So when user presses paypal button, `onClick` is called by paypal with some arguments, and inside I call my validation function. What I'm trying to achieve is to have available the `actions` parameter, given by paypal, inside my `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks.

Comment: The `actions` variables *is* in scope in your asynchronous callbacks, through basic closure.

Comment: I don't get what i should do, can you elaborate please? Tried a bunch of different stuff, actions are never defined inside those callbacks, even if I pass them as parameters to the anonymous function

Comment: Is `actions` even defined inside `onClick`, i.e. outside of your ajax callbacks? If yes, then it should keep that value unless you reassign (or shadow) the local variable somewhere - which the code you posted doesn't.

Comment: ```actions``` is a parameter passed to ```onClick``` by paypal library logic. I'm not doing any reassignment inside ```onClick```. If I call actions inside onClick works, but if i call it inside a callback inside ```onClick``` it doesn't work anymore

Comment: And what exactly is the error you get?